# AWS S3 - Configuring Website access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html#s3-example-photo-album-scenario-prerequisites

This will eventually be altered to manage audio files rather than images.

I have followed the guide but must of missed something as I still get an Access Denied error when attempting to listObjects.

I have created a bucket on S3
  - it is not a public bucket
  - region is EU (London) so eu-west-2 
 CORS config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The access control list only shows access for the Account (long list of numbers/letters) with list, write, read bucket and write bucket permissions.

In the Amazon Cognito console I have an Identity pool, the identity pool has roles assigned for both unauthenticated and authenticated though I believe I will only be using unauthenticated?

The unauthenticated role has the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::thisusesmybucketname/*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then on my website I do:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.243.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getHtml(template) {
  return template.join('\n');
}

var albumBucketName = 'myactualname';
var IdentityPoolId = 'eu-west-2:lotsofcharacters';

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'eu-west-2',
  credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId,
  })
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3({
  apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
  params: {Bucket: albumBucketName},
});

listAlbums();

function listAlbums() {
  s3.listObjects({Delimiter: '/'}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      //return alert('There was an error listing your albums: ' + err.message);
    } else {
      // we never get here
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Have I missed something here? If i go back to the bucket and set public access for read/write then it all works - however I am under the understanding that doing this is the wrong way to do it as it opens it up to anyone/everyone making use of my AWS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a problem with your S3 bucket policy. the listObjects call needs the permission to be set on the bucket, not on the objects in it.

In short, you need to add `"arn:aws:s3:::thisusesmybucketname"` to your Resource statement, so it looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::thisusesmybucketname/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::thisusesmybucketname"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's the one - as usual it seems so easy when someone else points it out. Added that and tightened up the bucket policy to be Referer specific and seems all sorted now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You are all doing it right, everything is just perfect. Now here comes the concept, you have made a serverless public website , which shows some images that anyone in public can see using client side temporary credentials that AWS Cognito provides to their browser.
But you have not given public read access to it, then how will they access them?

You have to make **ACL**, i.e. access control list, for objects that you want to be seen by public to **public-read** while uploading objects/images so that anyone can access those only objects that only you allow to do so.If you want public to upload too, then you have to provide write access also.

Other thing is giving public-read access to bucket doesn't mean public has infinite powers to your AWS account, they are intentionally provided a particular location from and to where they can interact with the storage service of your website.

here is the code how I am doing so:

```
var file = fileChooser.files[0];
if (file) {
    results.innerHTML = '';

var params = {
                    Key: 'maus/group1.jpeg',
                    ContentType: file.type,
                    Body: file,
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                };

                s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        results.innerHTML = 'ERROR: ' + err;
                    }else {
                        results.innerHTML = ' snapshot uploaded !!!';
                    }
                }).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {console.log(progress);});
} else {

            results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
        }
```

And if you want more stricter control over your bucket , then you can use **authenticated identity pools** to do so and then modify your code in such a way that a particular user can access particular objects in s3 bucket with username as prefix of objects he/she uploads.

e.g.
**yourbucketname/user1/*** is accessible to user1 only

**unauthenticated user pools** themselves mean that you want everyone to access a particular AWS resource using temporary credentials